# Why does this line order affect borrowed value lifetime?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Disclaimer: Learning Rust.

I have the following function:

```
fn log_action(log_file: &String, transferred_files_count: &i32) -> Result<()> {
    let mut lines = Vec::new();
    let count_as_string = transferred_files_count.to_string();
    lines.push(&count_as_string); // error
    append_lines_to_file(log_file, &lines)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

When trying to push `&count_as_string` into the vector, I get the error `borrowed value does not live long enough`. By accident, I noticed when I swap the two top lines, the error disappears:

```
fn log_action(log_file: &String, transferred_files_count: &i32) -> Result<()> {
    let count_as_string = transferred_files_count.to_string();
    let mut lines = Vec::new();
    lines.push(&count_as_string); // no error!
    append_lines_to_file(log_file, &lines)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

I am confused, in my opinion the order of those two lines should be irrelevant. Can someone explain the logic here?

Comment: You may also be interested in [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: Great tip, thanks!